# Solidity problem error space coding

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-migration, quorum

i'm facing a problem with coding the migration.sol 
how i can fix these error space!

-

[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract Migrations {
    address public owner;
    uint public last_completed_migration;

    modifier restricted() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }

    constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
last_completed_migration = completed;}


function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Comment: you'd make it easy if you copy/paste the code instead a screenshot

Comment: Read the [Solidity style guide](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html) and apply the rules to your code

Comment: @BadrBellaj i did

Comment: @Henk is there any extension i can installed to fix that?

Comment: @B-zero have you already installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity

https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/configuring-visual-studio-code

Comment: @BadrBellaj yeah but how to add it to visual studio?

Comment: read the second link in my comment

Comment: @BadrBellaj i did, but it doesn't work :(